# Python - Increment lower range boundary in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, increment

I'm trying to gradually increase the lower boundary of a range during a for loop. This is supposedly how it would work (I'm new to Python so assume complete ignorance):

```
start = 0
reset = bool

for i in range(start, 6):
    print(i)

    if i > 4:
        reset = True

    if reset == True:
        start += 1
        i = start
```

Ideally, this would have outputs like:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 *reset*

1, 2, 3, 4, 5 *reset*

2, 3, 4, 5 *reset

I tried the above code but to no avail..

etc.

This must be possible to do, no?
Note I'm trying to use this in a much more complicated nested 'for' loop and so ideally the solution would work with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not possible since `range(start, 6)` creates an iterator based upon the initial start value which i is sequencing through.  Changing start afterwards has no affect on this sequence of numbers.  You need a while loop.

Comment: You can use a combination of `while` and `for` loop for this.

Comment: A for loop in Python doesn't care about the current value of x (unlike most C-like languages) when it starts the next iteration; it just remembers the current position in the range and assigns the next value. In order to be able to manipulate the loop variable, you need to use a while loop, which doesn't exert any control over any variables (it just evaluates the condition you give it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

A single for loop won't work since range(start, 6) creates an iterator based upon the initial start value which i is sequencing through.

Changing start afterwards has no effect on this sequence of numbers.

**Try single while loop**

```
start = 0
i = start
while i < 6:
  print(i)
  i += 1

  reset = i > 4

  if reset:
    print('reset')
    start += 1
    i = start
```

**Output**

```
0
1
2
3
4
reset
1
2
3
4
reset
2
3
4
reset
3
4
reset
4
reset
5
reset
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for i in range(0, 6):
    for j in range(i,6):
        print("{}, ".format(j))
```

Output:

- i = 0 -> j = 0 1 2 3 4 5
- i = 1 -> j = 1 2 3 4 5
- i = 2 -> j = 2 3 4 5
- i = 3 -> j = 3 4 5

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

will not work!
the first time for enters, it evaluates "range(start, 6)" and uses that result! so even
if you change "start" after it is already done!

what you can do it is to use a while loop for your purpose

```
start = 0  
reset = bool

while start<6:
    print(i)

    if i > 4:
        reset = True

    if reset == True:
        start += 1
        i = start
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the loop control variable will do you no good here because:

```
for i in some_range:
    do_something_with(i)
```

is *effectively* the same as (Python-like pseudo-code):

```
i = some_range.start
while i != some_range.end:
    do_something_with(i)
    i = some_range.next
```

In other words, regardless of the changes you make to `i` within the loop, the loop itself will throw that away on the next iteration.

Something like this is probably a good starting point:

```
# Starting limits.

start = 0
stop = 6

# Outer loop responsible for resets.

while start < stop:
    # Disallow reset to start with.

    reset = False

    # Inner loop responsible for a single sequence.

    for i in range(start, stop):
        print(i, end=' ')

         # Whatever rule you need to trigger reset.

        if i > 4:
            reset = True

        # The actual reset that sets up and starts the next sequence.

        if reset == True:
            print()
            start += 1
            break
```

In that code, you actually have an *outer* loop that manages the resets. When it comes time to reset, you simply modify the parameters for the next outer loop and just break out of the inner loop:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5    
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
3 4 5
4 5
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update a `range` once it is declared. Alternatively use `while` and change the lower range at the end of the loop. You can have a separate variable `start` for initializing the `i` every time.

`print("")` is just a line break

```
k = 6
i = 0
start = 0
while i < k:
    print(i, end="")
    i += 1
    if i == k:
        print("")
        start += 1
        i = start
```